# Access violation reading location when calling cudaMemcpy2DToArray

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, cuda

I allocated a 2D array in device and want to copy a 2D float array to device.
ImgSrc is a Mat type in openCV that I copied the elements of it into a 2D float array named ImgSrc_f.then by using cudaMemcpy2DToArray() I copied my host 2D array(ImgSrc_f) to device 2D array Src.
size of 2D arrays are 512X512.

```
cudaChannelFormatDesc floattex = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
cudaArray *Src;
cudaMallocArray(&Src, &floattex, 512, 512);

float *ImgSrc_f[512];
for (int i=0; i<512; i++)
         ImgSrc_f[i] = (float *)malloc(512 * sizeof(float));
for(int i=0;i<512;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<512;j++)
    {
        ImgSrc_f[i][j]=ImgSrc.at<float>(i,j);
    }
//copy from host memory to device
cudaMemcpy2DToArray(Src, 0, 0,ImgSrc_f,512 * sizeof(float),512 *sizeof(float), 512,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

but I got this exception:

```
Access violation reading location 0x0000000000281000
```

Comment: Why construct the intermediate host array at all? I would be incredibly suprised if if were not possible to directly copy from the source image to the device array. Even if you need to do some sort of transformation on the data before binding to a texture, I would guess it will be faster on the GPU, just because of the superior memory bandwdith

Comment: @talonmies For all we know, `Mat` is a sparse matrix which would not have its data as a block of contiguous memory. It wasn't specified in the question, although I assume that that is not actually the case.

Comment: @AviGinsburg: Eh? The question says the input is an [OpenCV Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat), which is a dense matrix, stored in pitched linear memory

Comment: @talonmies Oops, I misread that first line. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ImgSrc_f` does not point to a contiguous 512x512 chunk of memory. Try changing

```
float *ImgSrc_f[512];
for (int i=0; i<512; i++)
         ImgSrc_f[i] = (float *)malloc(512 * sizeof(float));
for(int i=0;i<512;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<512;j++)
    {
        ImgSrc_f[i][j]=ImgSrc.at<float>(i,j);
    }
```

to something like

```
float *ImgSrc_f;
ImgSrc_f = (float *)malloc(512 * 512 * sizeof(float));
for(int i=0;i<512;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<512;j++)
    {
        ImgSrc_f[i * 512 + j]=ImgSrc.at<float>(i,j);
    }
```

`cudaMemcpy2DToArray` [expects](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g1cc6e4eb2a5e0cd2bebbc8ebb4b6c46f.html) the source pointer to point to a single contiguous block of memory.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have another question.Do you think is this a optimized way to copy a Mat variable to a 2D float array like this?because speed in my code is important and exactly because of that I asked this question.

Comment: No. But that depends on what `Mat` is. But, post a new question as such with all relevant info and I'm sure someone will point you in the right direction.